# Autoscroll on TRichView (lazarus)

Tags: linux, gtk, lazarus, fpc

Some hint to to make works a autoscroll in TRichView?

I've try to use this:

```
my_richview.Perform(EM_LINESCROLL, 0, my_richview.Lines.Count - 1);
```

It doesn't work:

> unitmessage.pas(101,45) Error: Identifier not found "EM_LINESCROLL"

Answer (score 0):

In the end I changed the richview to SynEdit and now it is OK.